# Solving $T(n)= T(\frac n 2) + 2 T(\frac n 4) + n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

> Solve $T(n)= T(\frac n 2) + 2 T(\frac n 4) + n, T(1)=1$

Each vertex in the tree has 3 children, we have up to the $\log _4 n $ level a complete tree, that has $3 ^{\log_4 n}$ vertices on that level. The last level is $\log_2 n$ and it has $3 ^{\log_2 n}$ vertices. In each level we have $n$ "work", so we get that:

$$n3^{\log_4 n}= n \sum_{i=0}^{\log_4 n}3^i \le T(n) \le  n \sum_{i=0}^{\log_2 n}3^i \le T(n)=n \frac {1-3^{\log_2 n}}{-2}= n3^{\log_2 n}$$

Now both $3^{\log_4 n}, 3^{\log_2 n}$ are very similar to $3^{\log_3 n}$, so does it simply follow that $T(n) = \Theta (n\cdot n) = \Theta (n^2)$ ? Is this considred a legal move?

Edit: found my error, I should summed (amount of levels) * (work in each level) instead of (amount of leaves in each level)*(work in each level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we start by solving the following recurrence:
$$T(n) = T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + 2T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor) + n$$
where $T(1) = 1$ and $T(0) = 0.$

Now let $$n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^k$$
be the binary representation of $n.$
We unroll the recursion to obtain an **exact** formula for $n\ge 1$
$$T(n) = \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
[z^j] \frac{1}{1-z-2z^2} 
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^{k-j}.$$

Studying the generating function  we use partial fractions by residues
on the simple poles to get

$$ \frac{1}{1-z-2z^2} 
= \frac{1}{z+1}\frac{1}{-1-4(-1)}
+ \frac{1}{z-1/2}\frac{1}{-1-4(1/2)}
\\ = \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{z+1}
-\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{z-1/2}
= \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{z+1}
+ \frac{2}{3} \frac{1}{1-2z}.$$

This yields
$$ [z^j] \frac{1}{1-z-2z^2} 
= \frac{1}{3} (-1)^j + \frac{2}{3} 2^j.$$

The new exact formula becomes

$$T(n) = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
(-1)^j \sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^{k-j}
+ \frac{2}{3}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
2^j \sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^{k-j}.$$

We now compute lower and  upper bounds which are actually attained and
cannot  be improved upon.  For the  lower bound  consider a  one digit
followed by a string of zeroes, to give

$$T(n) \ge \frac{1}{3}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
(-1)^j 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor-j}
+ \frac{2}{3}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
2^j 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor-j}
\\ = \frac{1}{3} 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}
\frac{1-(-1/2)^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1}}{1-(-1/2)}
+ \frac{2}{3} (\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1)
2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}
\\ = \frac{2}{9} \left(2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
+ \frac{1}{2} (-1)^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}\right)
+ \frac{2}{3} (\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1)
2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}.$$

We see that the dominant term here is 
$$\frac{2}{3} \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor
2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}.$$

For an upper bound consider a string of one digits to get

$$T(n) \le 
\frac{1}{3}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
(-1)^j \left(2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor - j + 1} - 1\right)
+ \frac{2}{3}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
2^j \left(2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor - j + 1} -1 \right).$$

Recognizing  the terms  we already  computed in  the lower  bound this
becomes

$$T(n) \le
\frac{4}{9} \left(2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
+ \frac{1}{2} (-1)^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}\right)
+ \frac{4}{3} (\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1)
2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}
\\ - \frac{1}{6} \left(1+(-1)^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}\right)
- \frac{2}{3} \left(2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1}-1\right).$$

Collecting like terms finally yields
$$T(n) \le
\frac{4}{9} 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
+ \frac{1}{18} (-1)^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}
+ \frac{1}{2} + 
\frac{4}{3} \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor
2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}.$$

We see that the dominant term here is 
$$\frac{4}{3} \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor
2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}.$$

Joining the  upper and the lower  bound we get for  the asymptotics of
this recurrence that it is

$$T(n)\in\Theta
\left(\lfloor \log_2  n \rfloor 2^{\lfloor \log_2  n \rfloor}\right)
= \Theta\left(\log_2 n \times 2^{\ \log_2  n}\right) 
= \Theta(n \log n),$$

which, let it be said, could  also have been obtained by inspection or
from the Master theorem.

**Remark.** Note that on the lower bound the floor on the logarithm is
exact and we get 
$$\frac{2}{3} \log_2 n
2^{\log_2 n} = \frac{2}{3} n \log_2 n.$$

On the upper bound the floor on  the logarithm is off by about one and
we get
$$\frac{4}{3} (\log_2 n - 1)
2^{\log_2 n - 1}
= \frac{2}{3} n \log_2 n - \frac{2}{3} n$$

which permits us to say that the dominant asymptotic is
$$\frac{2}{3} n \log_2  n.$$

This formula  is very stable  numerically which isn't always  the case
with approximations to these Master theorem type recurrences.

A closely related recurrence where the asymptotics are of a different type is at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596713/).